# Excel, condense table if cells have no value

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have a table where names are filled in row one, and number values may or may not be present in row two:

```
Aline | Henry | Marry
33    |       | 44
```

I need to present a new table only with columns which contain the number values:

```
Aline | Marry
33    | 44
```

Comment: Sort horizontally and then delete the columns without values.

Comment: As I understand it a pivot table cannot exclude columns with empty cells, unless I am wrong here?

Comment: You choose what a pivot table displays

Comment: What about using a 'helper' table alongside a pivot table. I.e - you could do an extra non used table like if(numbercell = "", "", else value

It wouldn't matter then if there were blank spaces of course. 

Then you could base a pivot table on that helper table

Comment: I assume the filter is good way to hide the row with empty cell.

Answer (score 2):

Copy the table into a new sheet, select the two rows of data and click the sort option under the data tab.

Then select option on the sort menu.

[image: Screenshot of the sort menu]
<sub>(source: [imgh.us](https://imgh.us/SCR1_1.png))</sub>

Then select 'Sort left to right' on the radio menu that's displayed.

[image: Screenshot of the sort menu's options]
<sub>(source: [imgh.us](https://imgh.us/SCR2_1.png))</sub>

Once you have set up your sort exactly as in the first screenshot, you can click 'okay' and your table should be sorted so that all the columns that have a numeric value in Row 2 are on the left. You can then just copy and paste this into a new table.